# Design rules for exception handling

Tags: rest, exception, ejb-3.1

I want to catch a exception for particular scenario in ejb layer, and then rest layer should throw 401/Access denied http code corresponding to this scenario.

I already have a application specific exception that all service layer method throws.
To design it, I have 3 options:

1. Create a new exception and throw that from ejb layer and then check
   if exception is of type  then throw 401 from rest
   layer.
2. create httpCode member variable in pre defined application specific
   exception.
3. handle that scenario in rest layer

The problem with 2nd option I think is that service layer shouldn't know ant UI layer, but in this case, by adding httpCode I'm tying ejb to rest layer.

Well, regarding 1st option, I don't know, if it is a good design approach?

About 3rd option, I feel is not a good approach as rest layer, should only call service layer. Any business logic should stay out of it.

Should I go with 1st option or is there any other better approach that I can take here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1) is the better design in my opinion: the lower layer (service) should not need to know any specifics about the upper layer (UI).